# nvd3 clickable axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I have a simple, stacked horizontal bar chart. I want the y-axis labels to be clickable, ie; I want them to work just like an `<a href='...'>` tag.

Here is a snippet of my graph. When the text 'site1', 'site2', etc, is clicked on I want it to take the user to the underlying url.

How do I do this?

[image]

Here is some sample JSON backing the chart (see `graphData` in the chart building code):

`[
    {
        "key": "Redirect",
        "values": [
            {
                "label": "site1",
                "value": 300
            },
            {
                "label": "site2",
                "value": 300
            },
            {
                "label": "site3",
                "value": 300
            },
            {
                "label": "site4",
                "value": 300
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "Response",
        "values": [
            {
                "label": "site1",
                "value": 634.6369999228045
            },
            {
                "label": "site2",
                "value": 529.6729999827221
            },
            {
                "label": "site3",
                "value": 525.2909999107942
            },
            {
                "label": "site4",
                "value": 535.6699998956174
            },
        ]
    }
]`

And the code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .margin({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 100})
        .groupSpacing(.1)
        .stacked(true)
        .showControls(true);
        //.showValues(true);

    chart.tooltip.enabled();

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

    d3.select('#chart svg').datum(graphData).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: it'd be best if you displayed the code

Comment: The code is pretty plain. Didn't think of adding it...but i updated the question with JSON and JS code if it helps.